# Не работает кнопка  submit

Tags: php

Есть такой код: при нажатии на кнопку "изменить данные", всплывает окно с тремя input для ввода и кнопка submit, но где-то ошибка кнопка ничего не отправляет в файл INSERT.php при нажатии.
Помогите пожалуйста.Вот код

```
<form action="/templates_alt/pages/INSERT.php" method="post">
```

<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="e" class="ui-corner-all">

```
  <div style="padding:10px 20px;">

    <h3>Введите № водомера</h3>
    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="num_vodomera"  placeholder="Введите номер"type="text">

        <h3>Введите дату поверки</h3>
        <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="poverca"  placeholder="Введите дату поверки"type="text">

        <h3>Введите дату след поверки</h3>
        <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="new_poverca"  placeholder="Введите дату след поверки"type="text">

        <button type="submit" name="submit" data-theme="b" >Сохранить</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает? А может это INSERT.php не обрабатывает? Может файл называется insert.php? "Фунционал кнопки" лежит уровнем поглубже и контролируется системными процедурами, так что не в кнопке дело. Покажите код INSERT.php.
И вообще, пробел надо ставить в "Введите номер"type="text". Все input имеют один и тот же name="text-17"????

Comment: @adzam, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: если я на чистой странице создаю форму ввода :
<form action="/templates_alt/pages/INSERT.php" method="post">
№ водомера: <input type="text" name="num_vodomera"><br>
Поверка: <input type="text" name="poverca"><br>
След поверка: <input type="text" name="new_poverca"><br>
<input type="Submit"></form>
то все работает чисто и записывается в базу данных если как в данном примере я использую форму ввода на всплывающем окне, так как  при нажатии кнопки "Изменить данные" всплывает окно с формой ввода и из него не отправляются данные из input-ов в файл php для обработки.прилагаю файл INSERT.php

Comment: @adzam..  форматируйте код в коментах тоже (4 пробела слева) ничего же непоянтно...

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)
Опишите здесь свою новую заметку.

Comment: Ну, учитывая то факт, что исходник вы поправили по примеру в ответе, но все равно утверждаете, что "кнопка не работает", то пора дать еще совет - кнопка работает, и данные шлются через POST и INSERT.php их получает, поверьте! Но что-то опять не так - может теперь в базу неправильно пихаем - возможно юзернэйм и пароль опять от балды в коде, которые, как мелочь "потом подправим"? :) Давайте разбираться.

Comment: нет с базой все впорядке.На пустой странице html создаю форму ввода

    <form action="/templates_alt/pages/INSERT.php" method="post">№ водомера:<input type="text" name="num_vodomera"><br> Поверка:<input type="text" name="poverca"><br> След поверка:<input type="text" name="new_poverca"><br> <input type="Submit"></form> 

и данные записываются правельно в базу данных я проверял, а из этого окна не хочет и все, уже мозг взрывается с утра сижу и колдую

Comment: пробовал заменить на на

<input type="submit" />

не помогает, то же никакой реакции

Answer (score 2):

У вас

```
$num_vodomera = $_POST['num_vodomera'];
$poverca = $_POST['poverca'];
$new_poverca = $_POST['new_poverca'];
```

а имена полей формы имеют названия **text-17**, причем все.

" мелочи как одинаковые id я потом подправлю " - вот когда подправите name-ы (приведете их в соответствие с именами, указанными в $_POST), тогда и заработает, потому что ваш скрипт  не телепат, чтобы догадываться, из какого поля формы приходит значение. Вообще феноменальный ответ по типу "машина не едет - что делать? Бензина-то нет вообще, но я потом его залью, но сейчас почему не едет?"

Вот как правильно (обратите внимание на значения аттрибутов name - они совпадают с теми, которые ожидаются в INSERT.php):

```
<form action="/templates_alt/pages/INSERT.php" method="post">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <h3>Введите № водомера</h3>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">

     <input data-clear-btn="true" name="num_vodomera" id="text-1" value="" placeholder="Введите номер" type="text"></div>
     <h3>Введите дату поверки</h3>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">

     <input data-clear-btn="true" name="poverca" id="text-2" value="" placeholder="Введите дату поверки" type="text"></div>
     <h3>Введите дату след поверки</h3>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">

     <input data-clear-btn="true" name="new_poverca" id="text-3" value="" placeholder="Введите дату след поверки" type="text"></div>
     <button type="submit" data-theme="b" >Сохранить</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: сделал и все равно ,жмешьна кнопку и ничего не происходит.
может method="post" не работает в jquerymobile. Я на ней делал всплывающее окно ввода, из простой html страницы работает все а здесь не хочет

Comment: jquerymobile тут ни причем - слать POST не ее, библиотеки, дело (имеется ввиду уровень топологии).
Что будет, если вместо 

    $num_vodomera = $_POST['num_vodomera'];

временно написать

    echo $num_vodomera = $_POST['num_vodomera'];

?
Напишите, что видно в браузере.

Comment: никаких изменений ,база не получает ничего

Comment: Что пишет на 

    echo $num_vodomera = $_POST['num_vodomera'];

с ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL)?

Comment: вообще ничего не пишет , форма ввода даже не запускает php, кнопка нажимается, цвет меняет и все никаких действий

Comment: Ну с этого надо было и начинать и указать, что переход по URL не происходит. И так во всех браузерах?

Comment: я всегда работаю в mozile в других не пробовал пробовал кнопке дописывать событие OnClick  и указал адрес INSERT.php php запускался и записывал в базу пустые строки т.е. не получал ничего от input-ов

Comment: Значит дело в клиентской стороне, т.е. связке HTML+JavaScript.

Попробуйте заменить

    <button type="submit" data-theme="b" >Сохранить</button>

на

    <input type="submit" />

DOCTYPE-ы какие?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$num_vodomera=$_POST['num_vodomera'];
$poverca=$_POST['poverca'];
$new_poverca=$_POST['new_poverca'];
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="moia";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or
die( "Unable to select database"); 
$query = "INSERT INTO vodomer VALUES
('','$num_vodomera','$poverca','$new_poverca')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

если надо то могу дать полный код формы, а мелочи как одинаковые id я потом подправлю они не используются у меня

Comment: Заметил такое , что если форма ввода

    <form action="/templates_alt/pages/INSERT.php" method="post"> №  водомера:
    <input type="text" name="num_vodomera">
    <br> Поверка:
    <input type="text" name="poverca">
    <br> След поверка:
    <input type="text" name="new_poverca">
    <br> <input type="Submit">
    </form>

находится на html странице то все работает, а если я ставлю ее на php страницу то она уже не работает, а почему?

Comment: Выложите полный код той самой страницы на http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

у меня такая же фигня была с <button></button> там надо в сам тег записать действие

типа что-то вроде этого:
http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/formtarget

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю решил ли adzam данную проблему. У меня тоже такое произошло. Нигде ответа нет. Я решил это некорректным способом. Поставил в коде копию неработающей формы выше с `style="display: none"` и та что ниже заработала. Для тех кто "в танке":

```
form style="display: none"
/form br/
form
```

Форма которая начала работать

```
/form
```